# Did other men besides Krishna indulge in sex in Vrindavan Raasleela?

Tags: puranas, krishna, sex, radha, vrindavana

It is [mentioned in the Brahmavairvata Purana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/44102/23709) that Krishna engaged in sex with Gopis in Vrindavan.

My question is, did the other men of Vrindavan also indulge in sexual intercourse during the Raasleela, or was it only Krishna engaged in it?

I am asking this because, as Krishna is God, he is also Brahmchari (he is Para-Brahma), and thus to him doing sex doesn't mean anything.

But did the other men also indulge in sex?

Comment: No. Krishna was the only male within the Rassmandala.

Comment: sex is very gross word, I wouldn't use it for divine being like bhagwan Krishna. I would use "raasleela" instead. Just my opinion.

Comment: There was no inter course during Rasaleela. The guy was an 8-11 year old kid when rasaleela was happening. If he touches a Gopi that doesn’t amount to sexual inter course. Raasa leela is just dancing and frolicking together and while doing so there is physical contact like touching the face, eyes, chest etc.

Comment: @Adiyarkku It is mentioned in BrahmVairvata Purana , that he engaged in sexual intercourse with Gopis. You can follow the link that I have provided.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto It is mentioned in BrahmaVairvat Purana that sex occured. You can follow the link in the question.

Comment: I think there is not only huge misunderstandings and interpolations and part of the misunderstandings is things that are figurative and then people take them literally. Also looks to me that stuff that seems like it’s figurative is sometimes actual facts (“That do be facts tho” Haha:D  So everyone getting cornfuzed here imo  There may not have been sex in this situation, could be meant figuratively but I don’t know for sure.

Comment: @devibhakt I don't understand what you are saying?

Comment: @TerjijKassal Saying it could be misunderstanding or interpolation, and if a misunderstanding, could be that the text is meant figuratively. I don’t know for sure though. But I think these kind of questions are interesting and end up in interesting debates where get to hear many different opinions and different ideas about Hindu texts, which imo is good thing 

Comment: HG Amogh Lila Prabhu mentioned in one of his discourses that Lord Shiva also participated in the Raas Leela;but don’t know of any further details.